# How to center a menu using <div>

Tags: html, css

I've tried this:

Code:

```
<div class="center">
    <div class="mainmenuoption">Home</div>
    <div class="mainmenuoption">About Us</div>
    <div class="mainmenuoption">Experiences</div>
    <div class="mainmenuoption">Get Involved</div>
    <div class="mainmenuoption">Support Us</div>
    <div class="mainmenuoption">Contact Us</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div.center
{
    display: block;   
    margin-left: auto;   
    margin-right: auto;
}

div.mainmenuoption
{
    float: left;
    font: normal normal bold 100% "Trebuchet MS", "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Grande", "Lucida Sans", Arial, sans-serif;
    width: 100px;
    color: #FFFF00;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Comment: This should be a `ul` with items, not a `div` with `div`s.

Comment: Are you trying to center the menu items inside the menu or center the menu itself when it's inside a parent element?

Comment: I'm trying to center the parent.

Comment: Please [don't use signatures or taglines in your posts](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#signatures).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you set an explicit width on your `div` it will expand to take up the available width.  Since you seem to know how wide you want it this will work:

```
div.center {
    width: 600px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

If the `div` might be of variable width use `display: inline-block` as Madara Uchiha suggested.

Comment: This worked.  The body is 900px width.  I tried you code, and it looks like it centered it.

Comment: Add a border to what?  If you have a new question, [ask a new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).

Answer (score 1):

Setting the inner `div`s to `display: inline-block` and the outer div to `text-align: center`, It should solve your problem.

Comment: You will want to also set the inner div to text-align:left, otherwise everything will be centered.

Answer (score 0):

Add a width to your `div.center` declaration or add `text-align: center` to your `div.center` declaration.

Answer (score 0):

Give `display: inline-block;` to the inner `div`s and a `text-align: center;` to the parent `div`.

```
<div class="center">
    <div class="mainmenuoption">Home</div>
    <div class="mainmenuoption">About Us</div>
    <div class="mainmenuoption">Experiences</div>
    <div class="mainmenuoption">Get Involved</div>
    <div class="mainmenuoption">Support Us</div>
    <div class="mainmenuoption">Contact Us</div>
</div>
```

#### CSS:

```
div.center
{
    text-align: center;
}

div.mainmenuoption
{
    font: normal normal bold 100% "Trebuchet MS", "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Grande", "Lucida Sans", Arial, sans-serif;
    width: 100px;
    color: #FFFF00;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/8Y8YW/

Comment: Did you remove the `float: left;`?

Answer (score 0):

if you want to **center the menu** (class `.center`) then you can use

```
.center 
{
     width:600px;   // what ever width you want
     margin: auto 0;
}
```

or you want to **center the menu item** use `text-align: center`

Answer (score 0):

If you set the width in your div.center, it should work! 
I posted a sample at: http://jsfiddle.net/EFXXs/2/